# Make a background image static?

Tags: html

So, I'm trying to make the background image static, and have the foreground content move over it. Having some issues, what am I doing wrong? Here is my current code.

```
body
{
color: #000;
margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px; 
background-color: #ffffff;
background-image:url('http://userlogos.org/files/backgrounds/Mafia_Penguin/Map1280x800.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set [the `background-attachment` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background-attachment) to fix the background image.

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```